# Is it possible to check a condition after every method in a loop? If so, how?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Like I said in the title I have a loop in an RPG I'm making about High School. This is the main loop that sets up your day to act out individual sequences in chronological order. My question is how could I make it so that I check whether the `boolean` "beat" or the `boolean` "lost" (referring to the status of the game) has been tripped to true after every method in the loop but still keeping the methods together in a loop. Is nested if statements inside my while loop the only way?

```
while (!g.getBeat() || g.getLost()) 
{
    g.wakeUp();
    g.goToSchool();
    g.beforeLunch();
    g.lunchActivity();
    g.afterLunch();
    g.afterSchool();
    g.home();
    g.sleep();
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  Is it the case that the game can end at any one of those points?

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) modeling each of these activities as a method on `g`, it might make sense to express it as a `Runnable`. That would let you express your sequence of steps as an `Iterable<Runnable>`, which would make it much easier to express logic such as "after each step, check _____".

Comment: @Makoto yes thats exactly it

Comment: @ruakh I like your thinking, however as I am in a class that hasn't been taught how to use `Runnable` yet, I won't be using it on this project. Thank you for letting me know of it though.

Comment: Using the terminating condition (or its negation) as a return code for all of these methods would let you write the concise `while( g.wakeUp() && g.goToSchool() && ... && g.sleep() ){}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do it manually. To help you write a little less code, make a method that checks both conditions:

```
private boolean stopTheLoop() {
    return g.getBeat() || g.getLost();
}
```

Now convert your loop to infinite with checks after each method:

```
while (true) {
    g.wakeUp();
    if (stopTheLoop()) break;
    g.goToSchool();
    if (stopTheLoop()) break;
    g.beforeLunch();
    if (stopTheLoop()) break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a switch statement by introducing a state :

```
int state = 0;
while (!g.getBeat() || g.getLost()) 
{
    switch (state) {
    case 0:
      g.wakeUp();
      break;
    case 1: 
      g.goToSchool();
      break;
    case 2: 
      g.beforeLunch();
      break;
    case 3: 
      g.lunchActivity();
      break;
    case 4: 
      g.afterLunch();
      break;
    case 5: 
      g.afterSchool();
      break;
    case 6: 
      g.home();
      break;
    case 7: 
      g.sleep();
      break;
    default:
      // some error handling, depending on your logic, 
      // or perhaps state = -1 to restart
    }
    state++;
}
```

Comment: @Makoto In what way does it feel wrong? I think that the fact that each action should take place after a specific action (for example, sleep() after home()), introduces a state implicitly, so why not add an explicit state?

Comment: The key word here is "state".  Using a loop feels like the wrong approach to me.  It's more of a state engine than anything else.

Comment: I agree with Makoto. This is known as a *[loop-switch sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence)*, and is usually considered an anti-pattern. In this specific case, it may not be exactly the usual anti-pattern, because there's somewhat of a reason for it; but you've still ended up with something much less maintainable than if you had simply added `if (stopTheLoop()) break;` after each method call . . .

Comment: I think maybe because it takes up so much vertical room that @Makoto feels it's just _wrong_.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any "built-in" way to do this, but with some coding, anything's possible.

First, regardless if how you handle this, I'd wrap the end condition into a single method, just to make things more convenient:

```
public class Game {
    // method, members, etc...

    public boolean isOver() {
        return !getBeat() || getLost();
    }
}
```

Now, The first option that comes to mind is to do this manually:

```
while (!g.isOver()) {
    g.wakeUp();
    if (g.isOver()) {
        break;
    }
    g.goToSchool();
    if (g.isOver()) {
        break;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

But this involves a lot of code, and isn't too elegant.

A more OO approach, perhaps, would be to warp every such call in a handler class:

```
public abstract GameStageHandler (Game g) {
    protected Game g;

    public GameStageHandler (Game g) {
        this.g = g;
    }


    /**
     * Play a stage in the game
     * @return Whether the game should go on or not after this stage
     */
    public boolean play() {
        performStage();
        return !g.isOver();
    }

    public abstract void performStage();
}
```

And implement it for every stage of the game. E.g. for the `wakeUp()` stage you'd have:

```
public abstract WakeUpHandler (Game g) {
    public WakeUpHandler (Game g) {
        super(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void performStage() {
        g.wakeUp();
    }
}
```

Then, in the main method, you could have an array of such handlers, and iterate over them:

```
List<GameStageHandler> handlers = ...;
while (!g.isOver()) {
    for (GameStageHandler handler : handlers) {
        if (!g.play()) {
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: As the game does not have that many methods to run through each iteration of the loop (each day), the second way you describe with an abstract and all is just too complicated. However, if I had a list of maybe 100 of these methods, your option would be quite appealing.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably beyond the scope of your assignment, as you noted the class hasn't even covered `Runnable` yet. This is an interesting question, though, and the challenge is to come up with a concise and elegant way to represent it, while avoiding as much repetition as possible. Here's a solution that uses Java 8 and functional programming techniques.

The first insight is to see that each game action or step can be represented as a lambda expression or method reference. I'll assume that you have a `Game` class. Each such step takes a `Game` instance as an argument (or receiver) and thus can be typed as a "consumer" of `Game` instances. We can thus put them into a data structure:

```
List<Consumer<Game>> actions = Arrays.asList(
    Game::wakeUp,
    Game::goToSchool,
    Game::beforeLunch,
    Game::lunchActivity,
    Game::afterLunch,
    Game::afterSchool,
    Game::home,
    Game::sleep);
```

Now that we have them in a data structure, we can loop over them:

```
for (Consumer<Game> action : actions) {
    action.accept(game);
}
```

Of course, we want to check if the game is over after each action. Let's assume you have a method `isOver` on the `Game` class that checks the right termination conditions. You can then do:

```
for (Consumer<Game> a : actions) {
    a.accept(game);
    if (game.isOver()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

That only runs through one day of the game. Presumably you want to run the game indefinitely until it reaches its termination condition. For that you need an outer loop, and the termination check has to break out of the outer loop:

```
outer:
while (true) {
    for (Consumer<Game> a : actions) {
        a.accept(game);
        if (game.isOver()) {
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

This by itself might be sufficient: you have a list of game actions, and a loop that runs indefinitely, checking the termination condition after each action.

But wait, there's more! There's still a fair amount of boilerplate here, which can be eliminated using some of Java 8's stream features. Consider that every element of a stream can be tested against a predicate using the `noneMatch` method. This method terminates when one of the predicates returns true.

Since each action has type `Consumer<Game>`, we need a little helper function that turns each action into a predicate:

```
static Predicate<Consumer<Game>> stepAndCheck(Game game) {
    return c -> { c.accept(game); return game.isOver(); };
}
```

Now we can run all the actions of a day as follows:

```
actions.stream().noneMatch(stepAndCheck(game))
```

To run the game indefinitely, we simply wrap this in a while loop. Since `noneMatch` returns `true` if, as it says, none of the predicates matches, we make this the loop condition and leave the loop body empty:

```
while (actions.stream().noneMatch(stepAndCheck(game))) {
    // nothing
}
```

This might seem like it's unnecessarily obscure. Indeed, it might be, for toy examples such as this. However, for more complex problems, techniques like this are quite valuable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep each step in its own method like you do in your example there is little you can do about it...

You can reduce the amount of code if you make all those methods to return "true" if the condition to stop the loop is met... however this might not be possible if you plan to use those methods in order context.

```
if (!g.getBeat() || g.getLost()) do {
    if (g.wakeUp()) break;
    if (g.goToSchool()) break;
    ...
    if (g.sleep()) break;
} while (true);
```

A possible trick is to make those methods to throw an exception if the stop condition is met. Then you would catch that exception in outside the loop. That way you would save the if (...) break statements. However this is not considered a good practice.

```
if (!g.getBeat() || g.getLost()) {
  try {
    do {
      g.wakeUp();
      g.goToSchool();
      ...
      g.sleep();
    } while (true);
  } catch (ActivityLoopFinished ex) {
    // nothing to do here
  }
}
```

Comment: No wonder my teacher loves/hates the kid who always suggests using a try catch as his only error handling.